How do Christians rationalize Job's children being treated like chess pieces?
I received this "question" from another user who defined immorality as "treating people like things", and must confess that I don't have a ready response.
In the book of Job, God permits Satan to kill Job's children in order to test Job. While acknowledging the difference between direct action and permitting, it still seem very... questionable that God would allow other humans to be (ab)used in this manner. (Even more cynically, the user claims that the later children described at the end of the book of Job are 'replacements, as if Job's children are interchangeable'.)
What is a (mainstream) Christian response to this objection?

The claim is inaccurate, see chapter 2. God doesn't permit Satan to kill Job's wife, which I think is significant, since it clearly refutes the slanderous claim that the Bible considers a man's wife to be his "property".

@user111403, my bad, shows what I get for taking the objection at face value and not fact-checking whether it's even correct. Fixed.

I don't like the premised definition of immorality, that is, using people as things. This is a very sloppy definition that excludes acts we would consider sinful that don't strictly use other people. For instance, blasphemy would not be immoral under this definition. It strikes me as a very modern liberal-progressive definition, a sort of hippie live-and-let-live understanding of morality. It also seems to exclude ignoring duties (eg to feed a starving man on one's doorstep) from immoral acts generally.

My comment might seem merely tangential at first, but it gets at the root of why you cannot think of a way to answer this person. By stepping into his or her philosophical framework that all immorality consists in treating people as things, he or she is able to claim God did just that in the story of Job. But morality is far more nuance than this. It can't be distilled to a single rule. Even our Lord needs to give us two rules to sum up the whole law.

@jaredad7, sorry, I should be more clear; I don't mean to say that that is (necessarily) the extent of this person's definition of "immorality". In order to be valid, your argument would need to either show a) that Job's children weren't "treated like pawns", or b) that doing so wasn't immoral in at least this instance. Just saying "this is an incomplete definition of (im)morality" doesn't accomplish either of those. "Love your neighbor as yourself" seems consistent with "don't treat other people like things".

@Matthew looking through the answers already presented, I think we can begin to piece together a good case. I may try to do so in a little while, after I'm finished with work.

How were Job’s children treated? Let us begin with:

Every good gift and every perfect gift is from above, coming down from
the Father of lights with whom there is no variation or shadow due to
change. (James 1:17, ESV)

Job was commended by God because he feared God and avoided evil. This righteousness thus came to him through the mediation of the spirit of the fear of the Lord. Therefore the good fruits of Job’s life were gifts from God. Any who received good gifts from Job were thus receiving good gifts from God.
What then did Job’s children receive from God? First, a mediator who interceded by prayer and sacrifice on their behalf lest they had sinned, even if only in their hearts.
Second, a father who taught them hard work, morality, charity and the value  of family. How many families of ten children feast together on a regular basis today?
Third, a prosperous life. The seven sons owned their own homes. Who helped them get a good start on life?
Fourth, vindication. Job’s friends accused his children of sinning, but God rebuked them for their words.
Fifth, dying together in their prime. His children did not die of long disease, of starvation, of the travails of old age. They died in the midst of feasting with people that they loved.
Sixth, a proper burial. Solomon speaks in Ecclesiastes of how horrible it is to not receive a proper burial. Job mourned his beloved children a long time.
Seventh, an eternal posterity. Solomon said that most people after they die are soon forgotten. When Job lost them, it shaped and changed him. Only a great loss could do that. It could not have been a great loss if his children did not love him. Their love for their father and his love for them were the fuel that deepened his faith, enabling him to find great insights through his prayers and debates and in the end pen (or dictate) the book which bears his name.
Those children did not die in vain. They were chess pieces to Satan, but not to God.

The question:

In the book of Job, God permits Satan to kill Job's wife and children in order to test Job... [it seems] very questionable that God would allow other humans to be (ab)used in this manner.

Developing an answer:
In essence, this is a variation on the biggest faith question of all: Why is there evil in the world? I would not presume to have a perfect answer, but would suggest these thoughts as important elements of any conversation.

It is indeed true that there is a sort of divine permission regarding acts of evil. This is true across the board, so that Job's family is not special in this instance. For example, we could ask, "Why does God allow rape, or assault? Why does God allow immoral world leaders to act in ways that result in thousands of innocent civilians being harmed? Why does God allow powerful businessmen to oppress workers through poor wages and working conditions?"

However the language of permission is really the language of human freedom. It is true that God could have created a world in which none of those bad actions happened. We ourselves have a template for this in the world of robotics. But a robot who cannot do wrong also cannot do right; it can only follow its pre-programmed actions. Freedom gives the opportunity for both good and bad actions. The same freedom which creates space for great selfishness, also allows for equally great self sacrifice. It is not possible for true relational love to exist if I could not have acted otherwise.

If this life were the whole story, the death of Job's family would be far more difficult to justify. But the claim of Christianity is that there is more to life than this life. Death is not the end. God is good, and God is righteous. It is possible to imagine a story line where God finally brings about true justice and restoration for his whole creation.

The story of Jesus Christ is critical to this. God ultimately is not apathetic to human suffering. "In Christ God was reconciling the world to himself." (2 Corinthians 5:19) The cross of Christ is a sign of great suffering, but also a sign of hope. We do not have all the answers, but we can trust in the God who does, and who will make all things new.

The overall story of Job reflects these elements. It is even possible that the whole book of Job is a fictional treatment to the problem of evil. After all, the narrative story is only an introduction to many chapters of philosophical discussion, all centred on the question: In the face of deep suffering, will our hero trust God or curse God? And to the extent that Job provides any answer at all to the problem of evil, it is God's final speech: "Where were you when I created the world?" The right response to all this is to leave the problem in God's hands.



I can't remember where I heard it, but I heard a preacher somewhere bring out a point about this.  In Job 42:10, we see that God gave Job "twice" what he had before.  Twice the sheep, twice the camels, etc.  But when you get to his children, it's the exact same number, not double:

[10] And the Lord turned the captivity of Job, when he prayed for his friends: also the Lord gave Job twice as much as he had before.
[11] Then came there unto him all his brethren, and all his sisters, and all they that had been of his acquaintance before, and did eat bread with him in his house: and they bemoaned him, and comforted him over all the evil that the LORD had brought upon him: every man also gave him a piece of money, and every one an earring of gold.
[12] So the LORD blessed the latter end of Job more than his beginning: for he had fourteen thousand sheep, and six thousand camels, and a thousand yoke of oxen, and a thousand she asses.
[13] He had also seven sons and three daughters.

In other words, God distinguished between Job's children and Job's stuff.  His children were eternal souls, and so they were not "replaced"; God simply added to the children he already had, and so now, he did indeed have twice the number of children.
I thought that was a neat point.  It may not answer all our questions about God's reasons, just like Job never had all his questions answered at the time.  But it reaffirms that God does indeed love us and has a plan.

Your answer piqued my curiosity so I went back to the book of Job. Chapter 1:18-19 confirms that his grown up sons and daughters were feasting and drinking wine when the house collapsed on them and the messenger confirmed they were all dead. This was the first test. The second test came later and this was when God told Satan he could test Job again but spare his life. Fast forward to chapter 42:12-15 and Job has seven sons and three daughters who he named as Jemimah, Keziah and Keren-Happuch. Clearly, they are not the same grown up daughters he had before Satan was allowed by God to test Job.

Your friend is right that it is wrong for us to treat other people as if they were our property; not primarily because we have inherent value that puts us beyond the realm of being owned, but because in treating other people as chattels we encroach on God's property.
However, God is under no such restriction when He deals with us, because we literally are His property. "He made us, and not we ourselves." He may do with us and to us whatever pleases Him. It is not necessary that we approve of His actions, or even understand His reason for doing them; His right to act does not depend on our approval or our ideas of right and wrong. If any of us managed to live sinless lives, He still would have been entitled to send such a person into eternal punishment. It is literally His divine right.
The end suffered by Job's first ten children is an example of God doing this. The children were given by God, and as Job acknowledged, God was within His rights to take them away, just as He took away everything else that was Job's.
Neither is it right to say that these children were treated as chess pieces. They were not manipulated in the way that pieces in a game are manipulated. The only person being manipulated was Job.

One is very much put off by your choice of nickname. But one has still up-voted your good answer.

"It is not necessary that we approve of His actions"... but if God were to torture people "for kicks", that would be a problem, whether or not He has a "right" to do so. God is not evil, therefore God will not engage in actions that are evil, even if they are "His right". Therefore, it is reasonable to seek to understand actions that seem evil.

It's the paradox of God's nature. His sovereignty entails that He may rightly behave in a capricious or even a malicious manner if it pleased Him to do so, and that we should accept it with patience; but His omniscience and His benevolence do not countenance such things.
